# insert string which double quotes in tag html

Tags: php, html

how could insert double quotes in html tag.

example:
php code:

```
$con = "the teacher said: \"hello\"";
```

return in php:

```
'<tagname name="'$con'">'
```

the problem is that it only takes the text until it finds the first double quote

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$con = "the teacher said: &quot;hello&quot;";
echo '<tagname con="'.$con.'">';
```

Use a `.` to concentrate strings. Because you can't include a double quote inside an HTML attribute, even when escaping it in PHP, encode the double quote as `&quot;`, which will show as `"`. If you want to do this automatically, run

```
$con = htmlspecialchars($con);
```

to automatically encode the string. You can run this inline by using

```
echo '<tagname con="'.htmlspecialchars($con).'">';
```

PHP manual: [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: This produces invalid HTML. The quotes must be escaped.

Comment: `%22` is URL encoding, it's going to appear as `%22` in HTML, not `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlspecialchars`:

```
echo '<tagname name="' . htmlspecialchars($con) . '">'
```

HTML raw:

```
<tagname name="the teach said: &quot;hello&quot;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here.

1. You are trying to concatenate strings without a concatenation operator. Use `.`
2. You have dealt with the problem of having double quotes in a PHP string that is delimited with double quotes but **not** with the other problem of having double quotes in an HTML attribute value that is delimited with double quotes. Use `htmlspecialchars`

Such:

```
'<tagname name="' . htmlspecialchars($con) . '">'
```